# Encrypting local data and SSO

Tags: android

We're working on a fairly enterprise-y app right now, and the mandate has been that all data be encrypted on the local disk.  Currently, the way to do this is to use the username/password entered on login to build the encryption key.  Those values are always kept in memory, so it would be reasonably difficult for somebody to hack that (not impossible, but difficult).

Now the app needs to use SSO to log in.  Depending on the provider, the implementations will differ, but lets say we can imagine some unique value being generated either by our server, or using the values available from the AccountManager, or something more exotic.  However its done, we need a way to build the encryption key from source values that aren't kept on disk.  As mentioned above, those are currently username/password, and for SSO, would be presumably something generated in another fashion.

If we were always online, we could rely on the server to keep that value in a database and return it on login.  However, this app should also be able to function offline (after you've done your initial login, of course).

Any thoughts?  I had explored just encrypting the whole disk, but we can't really enforce users doing that, and if there's a good chunk of data already, it'll take a long time.

Is there a way to keep these values somewhere in the OS that's not easily readable, even with root?  For example, if we had a lock screen, is there some way to use the lock screen password to hold encrypted data?  Its my understanding that that's the method used for the disk encryption, and there's something similar on iOS.  I've read in a number of places that a 4 digit code isn't not incredibly secure, but it would be pretty good, and much better than what we have now.

Any other thoughts?  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not ready to "answer" this yet, but we've been trimming down to the bare bones on this one, and I think there's no easy answer.  I think Android should allow apps to enable local data encryption tied to the lock screen.  That would solve a whole lot of enterprise issues in one solution, but I don't see that happening any time soon.